# layout.xml file has button, I can't figure out how to link each button to open a new preference screen

Tags: android, layout, button, onclick, preference

layout.xml file has button, I can't figure out how to link each button to open a new preference screen.

looking to rearrange my app, currently it's all preference screen, wantedto change it to revamp the UI a little to have buttons on the main page, and each one will open a new preference screen that I already have set up, any advice, I can't seem to figure out how to have it just open that already made preference scree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like going to another screen from a home screen, i'll do somethingl ike this:

```
ImageView floor = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.floor);
floor.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, WheelDemo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

floor is a button image, it starts the new activity, WheelDemo when it is clicked on and goes to a new screen for that activity. Jut make sure each activity is registered in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

First, how to get some Java code executed when you click on a button:

- in layout xml file, add `android:onClick="onSomethingDescriptiveClick"`
- in your activity, add a method `public void onSomethingDescriptiveClick(View caller) {}`

This method will be executed, when you click on a button in running app. Replace `SomethingDescriptive` with, uh, something descriptive. For example, if your button says "Preferences", the callback method could be `onPreferencesClick`.

Next, consult this to see how to start a new activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity

Answer (score 0):

I used a normal EditTextPreference but handled onPreferenceClick to cancel the dialog and catch the click.

```
 mbtnCheckUpdate.setText ("Check Updates.");
 mbtnCheckUpdate.setOnPreferenceClickListener( new OnPreferenceClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0)
        {
            ((EditTextPreference)arg0).getDialog().cancel();
            return true;
        }
    }
    );
```